# Unknown command beginning "administer..."

Tags: sql, oracle, encryption, tde

> SQL> ADMINISTER KEY MANAGEMENT CREATE KEYSTORE 'C:\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\NETWORK\ADMIN\WALLET' IDENTIFIED BY Welcome@123;
>   SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "ADMINISTER..." - rest of line ignored.

I have created a wallet and while creating a key I am getting the error as shown above. How can I resolve the issue? I have tried using " set sqlblanklines on;" , it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

That's only available in Database 12cR1 and higher. You're using 11.2.

[Here are the docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_1003.htm#SQLRF55976)

For 11g, you need to use the 
ALTER SYSTEM SET ENCRYPTION KEY and ALTER SYSTEM SET ENCRYPTION WALLET commands.

[Here are the docs.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28530/asotrans.htm#g1011122)

Comment: Thanks.
Using command
 SQL> alter system set encryption key identified by "Welcome@123";
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-28368: cannot auto-create wallet
But I have already created a wallet.